# Matlab Vector Replace Explanation

Tags: matlab

New to Matlab and reading someone else's code when I ran upon this:

```
A = [1:3;4:6;7:9;10:12];
A
m = zeros(4,1);
m
for j = 1:4
    [~,m(j)] = max(A(j,:));
end
m
```

I believe that the intention of the author was to store the maximum value of each row of A in the vector m. However, the code returns m = [3,3,3,3].

Two questions:

1. Why would replacement of a vector occur within parentheses?
2. What role is the ~ playing?

Though I'm open to any suggestions about ways to make this code run faster, I'd also like to figure out what's going on here. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? There was more to the question and answers than one could find by just reading the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may refer to the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html) of `max`.

Matlab functions have the ability to detect the number of input/output arguments. In this case, `max` realizes the user has designed 2 output arguments. Then it will work as defined in the 3rd line in "Syntax" (and described below) in the documentation.

Instead of the maximum VALUE, the INDEX of the first maximum element within the input is stored in the second output variable. In each iteration about `j`, `max` takes `A(j,:)`, which is a row vector, as its input. Since the last element is always the biggest, `3` will always be its second output. And it is stored in `m(j)`.

`~` in Matlab means ignore this argument. It is counted as an argument (so `max` has 2 output args), but Matlab will not store its output to any variable.

BTW `j` and `i` are not good iterators, because in Matlab they are assigned internally as the imaginary unity. Use `ii`, `jj`, or `m`, `n` instead.

Comment: thanks! I'm coming from R, where max() is just a plain old max. This makes sense in the wider context of the function.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [what Yvon has explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24973593/2586922), the code can be reduced to

```
A = [1:3;4:6;7:9;10:12];
[~, m] = max(A.');
```

This is because [`max`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/max.html) applied to a matrix works down each column. The `.'` in `A` is [matrix transpose](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html), so that now `max` will work along rows of `A`.

With this approach you work with the whole matrix at once, instead of looping over its rows. This is called [vectorizing](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html). In Matlab, vectorized operations are generally faster than `for` loops, and result in more compact code.